# Changing OS from Windows 10 to Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I have a 7 year old Hp pavilion dv6 laptop running windows 10 OS. I wish to change OS to Ubuntu and have downloaded the file but cannot get it to run. Looking at the list of HP computers which are compatible with Ubuntu the pavilion dv6 does not figure. Is there a way of changing my OS to Ubuntu without buying a new laptop ?

Comment: You certainly don't need to buy a new laptop. Although it is not listed, most hardware are readily compatible with Ubuntu. See https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Your laptop/computer meets the minimum requirements of ubuntu. Thus, you can install ubuntu easily.